# Why Model.objects.create() updates existing records

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I am using **django 1.4**. But i don't understand why `Model.objects.create()` method updates existing records while creating new value.

I was trying the same [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21486098/saveforce-insert-true-does-not-work-as-expected) using `Mode.objects.create()` but failed as it also updates existing records. It seem to be defect in **django ORM** architecture.

Comment: Can you provide a little more information? By default it shouldn't update any existing records unless something is listening to the save signals and modifying it for you.

Comment: So, thousands of projects using Django, and none of them have ever discovered this huge bug until now? Or could it possibly be your code, which you haven't shown us but which was written by someone with little knowledge if the framework, which is at fault?

Comment: It was my fault as there was a generic post_save signal on my model  updating the records. extremely sorry for blaming the framework.

Comment: When I was first accepted to computer engineering department we used to blame the compiler for all errors we had (they were teaching us c++ back then). It always turned out to be our fault every single time :) I just remembered that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should not be the case. `Model.objects.create` should not be updating existing records. I think you have some other issue here, maybe a custom `create` that does this or django signals that is responsible for side effects.

To debug this issue I suggest you to use `connection.queries` to see what kind of SQL is issued from ipython or django shell. Run `python manage.py shell` and run:

```
> from django.db import connection
> # Clear query list first
> connection.queries = []
> Model.objects.create()
> # See which queries are executed:
> print connection.queries
```